# Inputting a 6 digit number into an array

Tags: arrays, c

How do I ask for an input (ex:123456) into an integer array so that it is 1,2,3,4,5,6 in the array without using any punctuations or spaces?

```
int main(void)
{
    int input[7] = {0};

    printf("");
    scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d", &input);
}
```

Comment: `if (scanf("%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d", input, input+1, input+2, input+3, input+4, input+5) != 6) { /* error */ }` but it is a bad idea. Your best option is to use char arrays (aka *strings*)!

Comment: You could use a `for` loop, e.g. `for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {` `if (scanf("%1d", &input[i]) != 1) {` `/* error */` `}` `}`.

Comment: https://ideone.com/SWdjOA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf()` can't read directly into an array (except for strings), it requires a separate argument for each value you're reading.

And to read each digit separately without any delimiters, you have to specify the field size in the format string.

```
scanf("%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d", &input[0], &input[1], &input[2], &input[3], &input[4], &input[5]);
```

You can also use a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    scanf("%1d", &input[i]);
}
```